# why QdoublespixBox can't show big numbers correctly

Tags: qt, qspinbox

i have a problem with QdoublespinxBox

i'm using Qdoublespinxbox as a delegate in col2,

but when i have big numbes like 99999999999999999999999999999999

he can't show correctly , he shows me 1e+19

i have used this

```
    #include "customtableselldelegate.h"
#include <QDoubleSpinBox>
#include <QComboBox>
#include <QDebug>
#include <databasemananger.h>
#include <QLocale>
customTableSellDelegate::customTableSellDelegate(QObject *parent) :
    QStyledItemDelegate(parent)
{
}

QWidget *customTableSellDelegate::createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    if(!index.isValid())
        return QStyledItemDelegate::createEditor(parent,option,index);

    int col= index.column();

    if(col == 0)
    {
        DataBaseMananger dbMgr;

        QSqlQueryModel *queryModel = new QSqlQueryModel(parent);

        queryModel->setQuery("SELECT articleDesignation FROM articles");

        QComboBox *comboboxEditor = new QComboBox(parent);

        comboboxEditor->setModel(queryModel);
        //comboboxEditor->setEditable(true);


        return comboboxEditor;

    }
    else if(col ==1 || col ==2 || col ==3 ||  col == 5 || col == 6 || col == 7)
    {
        QDoubleSpinBox *doubleSpinBoxEditor = new QDoubleSpinBox(parent);
        doubleSpinBoxEditor->setRange(-999999999999999.99,999999999999999999.99);
        //doubleSpinBoxEditor->setSuffix(" D.A");
        doubleSpinBoxEditor->setDecimals(2);
        doubleSpinBoxEditor->setButtonSymbols(QDoubleSpinBox::PlusMinus);
        doubleSpinBoxEditor->setFrame(false);
        return doubleSpinBoxEditor;




    }else{
        return QStyledItemDelegate::createEditor(parent,option,index);
    }

}

void customTableSellDelegate::setEditorData(QWidget *editor, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    if(!index.isValid())
        return QStyledItemDelegate::setEditorData(editor,index);

    int col= index.column();

    if(col == 0)
    {
        QString data = index.model()->data(index,Qt::DisplayRole).toString();
        QComboBox *comboboxEditor = qobject_cast<QComboBox*>(editor);

        comboboxEditor->setItemText(comboboxEditor->currentIndex(),data);
    }

    else if(col ==1 || col ==2 || col ==3 ||  col == 5 || col == 6 || col == 7)
    {
        double data = index.model()->data(index,Qt::DisplayRole).toDouble();
        QDoubleSpinBox *doubleSpinBoxEditor = qobject_cast<QDoubleSpinBox*>(editor);
        doubleSpinBoxEditor->setValue(data);

    }else{
        QStyledItemDelegate::setEditorData(editor,index);
    }


}

void customTableSellDelegate::setModelData(QWidget *editor, QAbstractItemModel *model, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    if(!index.isValid())
        return QStyledItemDelegate::setModelData(editor,model,index);

    int col= index.column();

    if(col == 0)
    {
        QComboBox *comboboxEditor = qobject_cast<QComboBox*>(editor);

        model->setData(index,comboboxEditor->currentText(),Qt::EditRole);

        emit unlockRow(index);


    }

    else if(col ==1 ||col ==2 || col ==3 ||  col == 5 || col == 6 || col == 7)
    {
        QDoubleSpinBox *doubleSpinBoxEditor = qobject_cast<QDoubleSpinBox*>(editor);
        model->setData(index,doubleSpinBoxEditor->value(),Qt::EditRole);

        if(col == 1 || col == 2)
        {
            emit qtyPriceDataChanged(index);
        }



    }else{
        QStyledItemDelegate::setModelData(editor,model,index);}



}

void customTableSellDelegate::updateEditorGeometry(QWidget *editor, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    editor->setGeometry(option.rect);

}

void customTableSellDelegate::emitUnlockRow(QString str, QModelIndex index)
{
    emit unlockRow(index);

}


#include "customtableselldelegate.h"
#include <QDoubleSpinBox>
#include <QComboBox>
#include <QDebug>
#include <databasemananger.h>
#include <QLocale>
customTableSellDelegate::customTableSellDelegate(QObject *parent) :
    QStyledItemDelegate(parent)
{
}

QWidget *customTableSellDelegate::createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    if(!index.isValid())
        return QStyledItemDelegate::createEditor(parent,option,index);

    int col= index.column();

    if(col == 0)
    {
        DataBaseMananger dbMgr;

        QSqlQueryModel *queryModel = new QSqlQueryModel(parent);

        queryModel->setQuery("SELECT articleDesignation FROM articles");

        QComboBox *comboboxEditor = new QComboBox(parent);

        comboboxEditor->setModel(queryModel);
        //comboboxEditor->setEditable(true);


        return comboboxEditor;

    }
    else if(col ==1 || col ==2 || col ==3 ||  col == 5 || col == 6 || col == 7)
    {
        QDoubleSpinBox *doubleSpinBoxEditor = new QDoubleSpinBox(parent);
        doubleSpinBoxEditor->setRange(-999999999999999.99,999999999999999999.99);
        //doubleSpinBoxEditor->setSuffix(" D.A");
        doubleSpinBoxEditor->setDecimals(2);
        doubleSpinBoxEditor->setButtonSymbols(QDoubleSpinBox::PlusMinus);
        doubleSpinBoxEditor->setFrame(false);
        return doubleSpinBoxEditor;




    }else{
        return QStyledItemDelegate::createEditor(parent,option,index);
    }

}

void customTableSellDelegate::setEditorData(QWidget *editor, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    if(!index.isValid())
        return QStyledItemDelegate::setEditorData(editor,index);

    int col= index.column();

    if(col == 0)
    {
        QString data = index.model()->data(index,Qt::DisplayRole).toString();
        QComboBox *comboboxEditor = qobject_cast<QComboBox*>(editor);

        comboboxEditor->setItemText(comboboxEditor->currentIndex(),data);
    }

    else if(col ==1 || col ==2 || col ==3 ||  col == 5 || col == 6 || col == 7)
    {
        double data = index.model()->data(index,Qt::DisplayRole).toDouble();
        QDoubleSpinBox *doubleSpinBoxEditor = qobject_cast<QDoubleSpinBox*>(editor);
        doubleSpinBoxEditor->setValue(data);

    }else{
        QStyledItemDelegate::setEditorData(editor,index);
    }


}

void customTableSellDelegate::setModelData(QWidget *editor, QAbstractItemModel *model, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    if(!index.isValid())
        return QStyledItemDelegate::setModelData(editor,model,index);

    int col= index.column();

    if(col == 0)
    {
        QComboBox *comboboxEditor = qobject_cast<QComboBox*>(editor);

        model->setData(index,comboboxEditor->currentText(),Qt::EditRole);

        emit unlockRow(index);


    }

    else if(col ==1 ||col ==2 || col ==3 ||  col == 5 || col == 6 || col == 7)
    {
        QDoubleSpinBox *doubleSpinBoxEditor = qobject_cast<QDoubleSpinBox*>(editor);
        model->setData(index,doubleSpinBoxEditor->value(),Qt::EditRole);

        if(col == 1 || col == 2)
        {
            emit qtyPriceDataChanged(index);
        }



    }else{
        QStyledItemDelegate::setModelData(editor,model,index);}



}

void customTableSellDelegate::updateEditorGeometry(QWidget *editor, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    editor->setGeometry(option.rect);

}

void customTableSellDelegate::emitUnlockRow(QString str, QModelIndex index)
{
    emit unlockRow(index);

}
```

but really nothing makes a diffrent

Answer (score 1):

The default implementation of `QDoubleSpinBox::textFromValue(double)` returns a string containing value printed [using](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtbase/source/ae4c7be67d6a840a8d724bb1f986314cbbe47eb3%3asrc/widgets/widgets/qspinbox.cpp)

```
locale().toString(value, 'f', decimals());
```

This is never supposed to return anything but floating point representation. Testing it out separately, it definitely works and produces correct output:

```
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QLocale
int main(int, char **)
{
    QTextStream out(stdout);
    QLocale sysLoc = QLocale::system();
    double value = 99999999999999999999999999999999.;
    double max = 999999999999999999.99;
    int decimals = 2;
    //Q_ASSERT(value < max);
    QString str = sysLoc.toString(value, 'f', decimals);
    str.remove(sysLoc.groupSeparator());
    out << str << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

> 100000000000000005366162204393472.00

The output above is correct, by the way, it merely illustrates the limited length of mantissa.

Alas, your maximum value is not large enough to show either `1e19` or `99999999999999999999999999999999.`, so that may be your problem (the commented-out assert would trigger), but still it should not switch to the scientific format.

Most likely you're not applying your settings correctly to your spinbox, or your system locale is messed up. Make sure that the test code above works correctly.

Comment: i'm using custom delegate, really i don't figure out how code it

Comment: @advseo32: Show your code - edit the question. Custom delegate for what? A QML view? A QWidget-based view?

Comment: i'm using a custom delegate for simple qt program